# Why can't this const argument match a non-type template parameter?

Tags: c++, gcc, constants, constant-expression

When compiling the code below with gcc, I get an error: *'i' cannot appear in a constant-expression.*

Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
template<int p>
class C
{
public:
    void test();
};

template<int p>
void C<p>::test()
{
    p = 0;
}

char const *const p = "hello";
int main()
{
    const int i = (int)p;
    C<i> c;
}
```

Comment: You cannot assign value to the template param `p = 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `i` is not mutable at runtime because it is `const`, but it is not a "constant expression" because it is not evaluated at compile-time.

`(int)p;` is a `reinterpret_cast`. Integral constant expressions cannot have `reinterpret_cast`. It is explicitly forbidden (§5.19/2):

> A *conditional-expression* is a *core constant expression* unless it
>   involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated subexpression
>   (§3.2), but subexpressions of logical AND (§5.14), logical OR (§5.15),
>   and conditional (§5.16) operations that are not evaluated are not
>   considered [*Note:* An overloaded operator invokes a function.—*end
>   note* ]:
>
> — [...]
>
> — a `reinterpret_cast` (§5.2.10);
>
> — [...]